# how to pass multiple parameters through uritemplate

Tags: c#, .net, uri

how to pass multiple parameters through uri template

I Tried with some formats, not able to get the correct one

"/shoe"

"/shoe/*"

"{shoe}/boat"

“{shoe}/{boat}/bed/{quilt}”

“shoe/{boat}”

“shoe/{boat}/*”

“shoe/boat?x=2”

“shoe/{boat}?x={bed}”

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of your URI Template and your web request. If your URI template look like `shoe/boat?x={bed}`
Then your Web request should look like this

```
webservice1.svc/shoe/boat?x=2
```

Check [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1702719.aspx/1) for details
See the msdn article on [RESTful Services With WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx)